# Circular Dependencies / Incomplete Types

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, incomplete-type

In C++, I have a problem with circular dependencies / incomplete types. The situation is as follows:

Stuffcollection.h

```
#include "Spritesheet.h";
class Stuffcollection {
    public:
    void myfunc (Spritesheet *spritesheet);
    void myfuncTwo ();
};
```

Stuffcollection.cpp

```
void Stuffcollection::myfunc(Spritesheet *spritesheet) {
    unsigned int myvar = 5 * spritesheet->spritevar;
}
void myfunc2() {
    //
}
```

Spritesheet.h

```
#include "Stuffcollection.h"
class Spritesheet {
    public:
    void init();
};
```

Spritesheet.cpp

```
void Spritesheet::init() {
    Stuffcollection stuffme;
    myvar = stuffme.myfuncTwo();
}
```

- If I keep the includes as shown above, I get the compiler error
  `spritesheet has not  been declared` in Stuffcollection.h (line 4 in
  the above). I understand this to be due to a circular dependency.
- Now if I change `#include "Spritesheet.h"` to the Forward
  Declaration `class Spritesheet;` in Stuffcollection.h,  I get  the
  compiler error `invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Spritesheet'`
  in Stuffcollection.cpp (line 2 in the above).
- Similarly, if I change `#include "Stuffcollection.h"` to `class
  Stuffcollection;` in Spritesheet.h, I get the compiler error `aggregate
  'Stuffcollection stuffme' has incomplete type and cannot be defined`
  in Spritesheet.cpp (line 2 in the above).

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665912/double-include-solution/7665937#7665937 (that was posed by the same author not long ago!)

Comment: @EdHeal: I have the highest voted answer on that Q and it is not a duplicate. There is a subtle difference, You would know if you read carefully.

Comment: This isn't the *actual* code from your program. This code could not generate the error message you indicate. Please reduce your program to a minimal, complete sample program and copy-paste (**not** retype) that code here. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Als - I thourgh that the previous question it was obvious to `#include` in the .cpp files.

Comment: @EdHeal: Yes, but the OP didn't understand it & S/He won't if we just close this saying duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You should include `Spritesheet.h` in `Stuffcollection.cpp`
Just use forward declaration in the header file not the cpp file, that solves the circular dependency of the header file. The source file has no circular dependency actually.

`Stuffcollection.cpp` needs to know the complete layout of class `Spritesheet`(because you dereference it), So you need to include the header which defines the class `Spritesheet` in that file.

From your previous Q **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665912/double-include-solution/)**, I believe that class `Stuffcollection` is used in the class declaration of `Spritesheet` header file and hence the above proposed solution.

Comment: Thank you! Getting this to work really makes my whole code a lot simpler, since I can now finally remove all my workarounds (mainly copied functions...). About paragraph 3: I noticed that I don't need to include Stuffcollection.h into Spritesheet.h, it is sufficient to include it into Spritesheet.cpp.

Comment: Just noticed: Actually that is exactly what sth said :)

Comment: @Ben: Glad you could get it to work, Always post all relevant information with a Q that helps us answer your Q better, like in this case Your first Q indicated(Since You didn't show the code in that file but included it) probably you needed the include.

Answer (score 3):

Use this form for your nested includes:

## Stuffcollection.h

```
#ifndef STUFFCOLLECTION_H_GUARD
#define STUFFCOLLECTION_H_GUARD
class Spritesheet;
class Stuffcollection {
  public:
  void myfunc (Spritesheet *spritesheet);
  void myfuncTwo ();
};
#endif
```

## Stuffcollection.cpp

```
#include "Stuffcollection.h"
#include "Spritesheet.h"

void Stuffcollection::myfunc(Spritesheet *spritesheet) {
  unsigned int myvar = 5 * spritesheet->spritevar;
}

void Stuffcollection::myfuncTwo() {
  //
}
```

## Spritesheet.h

```
#ifndef SPRITESHEET_H_GUARD
#define SPRITESHEET_H_GUARD
class Spritesheet {
  public:
  void init();
};
#endif
```

## Spritesheet.cpp

```
#include "Stuffcollection.h"
#include "Spritesheet.h"

void Spritesheet::init() {
  Stuffcollection stuffme;
  myvar = stuffme.myfuncTwo();
}
```

General rules I follow:

- Don't include an include from an include, dude. Prefer forward declarations if possible.

  - Exception: include system includes anywhere you want
- Have CPP include everything it needs, not relying upon H recursively including it files.
- Always use include guards.
- Never use `pragma`

Comment: Another good rule: every .cpp should include its own .h first (so I'd switch the order of the includes in your Spritesheet.cpp). That way there is at least one .cpp that includes any .h without anything before it, thus ensuring that the .h is not missing any includes.

Comment: This way works for me, where I have included Alan's tip about including the h corresponding to the cpp first. Many thanks.

Comment: @Ben -- please upvote the answer(s) that helped you, and accept (by clicking on the check mark) the answer that helped the most.

Answer (score 2):

`Spritesheet.h` doesn't need to include `Stuffcollection.h`, since no `Stuffcollection` is used in the class declaration of `Spritesheet`. Move that include line to `Spritesheet.cpp` instead and you should be fine.