# another incomplete type Error C++

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular Dependencies / Incomplete Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666665/circular-dependencies-incomplete-types)

writing a litte c++ program and be confused....

got 4 classes, 2 important for this error...

got the error message "field 'dot' has incomplete type" in Line 13 and "expected ';' befor '(' token" in same Line

The Error seems to start in the Vector3.cpp, where only the include of the Vector3.h and the empty methodes

deleted the include "Vector3.h" in the Normal3 Header, thought will be running in a circle... not so well...

some ideas? hope so :) and ty for answers

Here are my two important classes:

```
#ifndef NORMAL3_H
#define NORMAL3_H


class Normal3 {


      public:

      double x, y, z;
      Normal3 mul(Normal3 n);
      Normal3 add(Normal3 n);
      Normal3 dot(Vector3 v); //Line 13

      Normal3(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0)
                     : x(x), y(y), z(z)
      { }   

};

#endif //NORMAL3_H
```

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAND

```
#ifndef VECTOR3_H
#define VECTOR3_H

#include "Normal3.h"

class Vector3 {

      public:

      double x, y, z, magnitude;

      Vector3 add(Vector3 v);
      Vector3 add(Normal3 n);
      Vector3 sub(Normal3 n);
      Vector3 mul(double c);
      double dot(Vector3 c);
      double dot(Normal3 n);
      Vector3 normalized();
      Normal3 asNormal();
      Vector3 refelctedOn(Normal3 n);

      Vector3(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0, double m = 0)
                     : x(x), y(y), z(z), magnitude(m)
      { }

};

#endif //VECTOR3_H
```

Comment: Wich line gives the error? line 13 where?

Comment: I don't think that normal should be a different type from <vector...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that the compiler does not know what `Vector3` is at that point. If you declare it in advance, the error will disappear:

```
#ifndef NORMAL3_H
#define NORMAL3_H

class Vector3;  // Add this line

class Normal3 {
  // ...
};
```

UPDATE: As [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1534269/john) says in his comment, it would be a good improvement to replace `#include "Normal3.h"` in Vector3.h with just another forward declaration, `class Normal3;`:

```
#ifndef VECTOR3_H
#define VECTOR3_H

class Normal3; // instead of #include "Normal3.h"

class Vector3 {
  // ...
};
```

You should try to keep `#include` directives in your headers to a minimum in order to avoid excessive compilation dependencies. You only need to include a header if it defines a type you are using (usually because a class you are defining has a data member of this type). If you are only using pointers or references to that type or function parameters of that type (as in your example), a forward declaration is enough.

Comment: I'd advise a similar change to vector3.h as well. Or since both classes seems quite tightly related put both into the same header file.

Comment: This is a differents classes. You can not use `forward declaration` for object, only for pointers and references

Comment: @Ruu: I am not sure of what you mean. I agree with john's suggestion, I am updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: Gorpik, Sorry, i made mistake. Instead `This is a differents classes` i went to say `This is a differents files`

Comment: really great, working, thanks, oke, will include less includes...

Answer (score 0):

your file `normal3.h` nothing know about `Vector3`.

I see that `Vector3 v` does not changes into `dot`, then you should write:

instead `Normal3 dot(Vector3 v); //Line 13`

as

```
#ifndef NORMAL3_H
#define NORMAL3_H

class Vector3;

class Normal3 {


      public:

      double x, y, z;
      Normal3 mul(Normal3 n);
      Normal3 add(Normal3 n);
      Normal3 dot(const Vector3 &v); //Line 13

      Normal3(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0)
                     : x(x), y(y), z(z)
      { }   

};

#endif //NORMAL3_H
```

Comment: got an error free compiling!! with this and the same changes in the Methode 'add' from Normal3.
Thanks, looking foreward for more code xD

Comment: Passing `v` as a `const` ref may be a good idea or not, depending on the actual implementation of `dot()`, but it is not necessary to solve the problem here. You can declare a function that gets a parameter of a forward declared type by value.